# Wifi hard blocked

Tags: networking, bluetooth

I am using ubuntu 16.04 amd64. First, i installed the wifi was working properly but after some time, the wifi got disabled and also the bluetooth. I run the command:

```
rfkill unblock all
rfkill list
```

It show the soft was not blocked but the hard block for wifi and the bluetooth is yes. I don't know how to switch off the hardware switch i tried <kbd>Fn</kbd> key but it's not working for me. I'm using a sony vaio laptop.

Answer (score 2):

I think the BIOS may have an option to enable it. Although I had a computer myself which had a switch on the right side, which I sometimes accidentally hit. Try finding any switches on the computer, if there aren't any, check your BIOS for any options on disabling hardware. If there's any more help you might need, I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Toshiba Satellite several times, and solved it doing either:

1. If you have a dual boot with Windows, and you disable your wifi in Windows, in my case it also blocked the wifi for Ubuntu.
2. Sometimes the laptop just "hangs" on the hard-blocking and the only way is to **remove your laptop battery**, which resets the BIOS (my laptop does not have a cmos battery).